# Variable transform output with fftw3 mpi and modern fortran: heap corruption? Round off error?

Tags: pointers, fortran, mpi, fftw, heap-corruption

I'm new to modern Fortran and am trying to write a lengthy program using FFTW3 and mpi with transposed output. In the process of debugging my (exploding) program, I noticed that the output of the transforms varies slightly from one execution of the program to the next. I wrote a small test program, which on my platform reproduces the variation, and which appears below. The "problem" doesn't appear for 64x64 or 128x128 arrays, but does for 512x512 arrays. The variation seems to be in the last few digits, and doesn't happen every time. (I have to run the program repeatedly to see it.) Does this suggest heap corruption? I couldn't find anything with valgrind. I searched stackoverflow and Googled but can't figure out what's wrong. Am I using pointers incorrectly? Is it just round off error?

I compiled fftw3 from source with the default double precision.

I'm compiling the program below with `mpifort -o fickledigits fickledigits.F90 -L/usr/local/lib/openmpi -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm`

```
    program fickledigits

    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    use mpi

    implicit none

    include 'fftw3-mpi.f03'

    !--------------------------------------------------------------------
    integer(kind=4)     :: np,id,ierr
    integer(kind=4)     :: i,j,it
    integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: L=512,M=L,LL=L/2+1
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: alloc_local,local_LL,local_M
    integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: local_kj_offset,local_i_offset

    real(C_DOUBLE), pointer            :: in(:,:)
    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), pointer :: out(:,:)
    type(C_PTR)                        :: data,plan_r2c,plan_c2r

    complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), target, allocatable :: qq(:,:)
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------

    call MPI_Init ( ierr )
    call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, np, ierr )
    call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, id, ierr )

    call fftw_mpi_init()

    alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_2d_transposed(LL,M,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
        local_LL,local_kj_offset,local_M,local_i_offset)

    data = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local)
    call c_f_pointer(data,out,[M,local_LL])
    call c_f_pointer(data,in,[2*LL,local_M])

    plan_r2c = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_r2c_2d(L,M,in,out,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
        ior(FFTW_MEASURE,FFTW_MPI_TRANSPOSED_OUT))
    plan_c2r = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_c2r_2d(L,M,out,in,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&
        ior(FFTW_MEASURE,FFTW_MPI_TRANSPOSED_IN))

    allocate(qq(M,local_LL))

    do i=1,local_LL
       do j=1,M
          qq(j,i)=dcmplx(j,i)
       enddo
    enddo

    out=>qq
    call fftw_mpi_execute_dft_c2r(plan_c2r,out,in)

    print*, 'in(10,10)=', in(10,10)

    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan_r2c)
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan_c2r)

    call fftw_free(data)

    deallocate(qq)

    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

    end program
```

Comment: Is the output ever different when comparing one-process runs only? Also, is the result the same when using wisdom? I'm asking because planning could give two slightly different plans each time, which *may* result in different roundoff in MPI.

Comment: You must show the output and tell as which output you expect instead. Follow the previous comments, start with single process run. What exactly makes you use the tag [tag:heap-corruption]? Tell us the info you have.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I haven't checked the result using wisdom. I did a bunch of one-process runs and didn't see any variation. With multiple processes the relative error is of order ~10^{-17}. The absolute difference depends on the numbers in question -- the last 3-4 digits are affected.

Comment: I used the tag "heap-corruption" because I had garbage randomly appearing in my long program (which is not the one shown above), and guessed that memory was getting corrupted. I didn't know what was wrong, and wanted to rule out the above variations as pathological, which is why I asked this question. It turns out I had not allocated an array correctly: switching to out-of-place transforms and allocating the real array with size `2*LL` (where `LL=L/2+1` ) using `call c_f_pointer(datar,in,[2*LL,local_M])` resolved the problem in the longer program. I had apparently misallocated my real array.